# open cv threshold function results

Tags: ios, opencv

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to binarize (Black & White) an image taken as a photo from iPhone/iPad.

as you can see in first image there is "blackness" on the bottom right while in this image its not that much in some of the other images it covers either bottom half or top half of the image

this is the threshold function that I'm using

cv::threshold(original, original, 30, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);

what could I do to make the results better and more consistent without this blackness?

i've tried blur and gaussionblur both before and after the threshold but it does not seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of varying light itensities over the page (the light source was put some where near the top-left corner). There's no cure with `cv::threshold`. Try `cv::adaptiveThreshold` instead.

Comment: I've tried adaptiveThreshold but the resulting image does not have as good of contrast as the cv::threshold any way to improve the contrast once adaptivethreshold is done?

Comment: You may try `cvEqualizeHist`

Comment: By the way, what you mean "contrast", as the resulting image should be a binary one...

Comment: meaning it had more grayish tone rather then being black & white as shown in the images in question